# I need a big regular polytope!

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

I have an ingenious project in mind that requires me to begin with a “big” graph of a regular polytope (# of vertices >, say, 50? 100?). This polytope can be of any dimension (I won’t be building it or drawing it). It only needs to be “regular” in the sense that each vertex has the same number of edges. That is, what I want is the chart that lists the connectivity between the vertices (I don’t even need their coordinates in whatever dimensional space this thing lives in). That is all I need. Ideally I would like a big polytope with five edges meeting at every vertex and as many edges as I can get. However, I can work with other vertex structures if I must. 1) Does such a thing even exist? 2) Is there a database of such polytopes with the vertex chart structure that I need?

Comment: Did you look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polytope)?  It describes the three infinite families of regular polytopes.

Comment: Thank you, I did see that. But my understanding is that each added dimension adds another edge to the vertex and although I seek lots of nodes, I want the nodes to have a limited number of edges each.

Comment: You are right that more dimensions means more edges at each vertex.  Do you really need a polytope, or is a 5-regular graph good enough as long as it has enough symmetry?  I can imagine a number of cycles with edges between them, for example.  On the other hand, a five dimensional cube has $32$ vertices and five edges at each vertex.  Is that large enough?

Comment: 5-regular is required but as soon as I saw the graphs suggested below I realized that a polytope is NOT what I need for my project. Now I need to find a graph that will work. This is going to take longer than I thought. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [House of Graphs](https://houseofgraphs.org/) has a searchable database of "interesting" graphs; you could try searching for large $5$-regular planar graphs (planarity would take care of your requirement that the graph comes from a polytope, if I'm correctly understanding that your "regularity" requirement doesn't need any algebraic symmetry). You could also try using [plantri](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/plantri/) to generate planar graphs, although some more assembly might be required there.

Comment: Thank you! Your tip was just what I needed. Sadly, I pretty quickly discovered that my “ingenious” idea had a fatal flaw and I probably need a more complex graph than a  5-regular planar graph. Thank you!